# How to draw a arc in vml

Tags: svg, vml

The following path draws an arc in ie 8 + and firefox. But in vml i cant able to draw the arc. Is there any way to draw the arc in vml without using raphael.

d="M 400 315 A 26 26 0 0 1 423 400 L 400 342 z"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The path posted seems like a SVG path. Similarly one can also provide paths to draw sahpes in VML. Try reading this: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML.

ex: A sample VML path for an arc would be similar to this: `path="m21600,qx,10800,21600,21600xe"` But one would also have to define formulas for the rendering application to interpret it. again I would suggest to read the above link to understand VML formulas.